# query for or change column name in php?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, json

I need to figure out a way to prepare an insert statement in `PHP` for a `SQL` db and I'm having trouble comprehending the logic. The insert statement will be from data I'm receiving in `JSON`. The `JSON` contains questions and answers. The table I'm inserting them into is the problem. On the front end (website) the table has column names that represent the questions and it look like this.

```
Date | Address | City | Zip
```

Now the problem is in the database these names don't carry over. The column names are just column1 column 2 etc. So it looks like this

```
Column1 | Column2 | Column3 | Column4
```

Another thing - when each table like this is created it will have different values so I can't hard code the relationship. Also these tables are created from importing an excel spreadsheet from the front end (website). So I came up with a plan to duplicate row 1 & 2 of the spreadsheet so that now when you import them the database looks like this

```
id | Column1 | Column2 | Column3 | Column4
 1 |   Date  | Address |   City  |   Zip
```

So now I have some reference to the values that will need to be inserted. Now the next steps involved will be.

1. Query for column name based on the data in row 1 **OR** change the column name to the data in row 1.
2. Insert data into the correct columns based on the query

So in summary I cannot insert the answers into the correct column representing the question without the proper information. I personally think changing the column names in `PHP` would be the better option. However I'm pretty new to `PHP` and `SQL` so I don't even know if this is possible. Any help is appreciated

**EDIT**

to give a slightly better understanding of the problem I am posting the `PHP` I currently have.

```
$json = safe($_POST['assessment']);
/*
$json = 
'{
  "info":
  [
    "Date: 6-22-13",
    "Phone #: (555) 555-5555",
    "Address: 304 N. SCOTTSDALE RD.",
    "City: SCOTTSDALE",
    "Zip: 85251",
    "State: AZ"        
   ]
}';
*/
$data = json_decode($json,true);
$collection = array();

foreach($data['info'] as $piece) {
   $info = explode(':', $piece);
   $collection[] = array('question' => $info[0], 'answer' => $info[1]); 
}
echo '<pre>'; print_r($collection); echo '</pre>'
```

Comment: Typically having arbitrary column names like "column1...column2...etc" is pretty poor practice.  I would suggest renaming them.  But the data...the data comes through mixed in with the field labels?

Comment: What does the JSON look like with the extra data containing the column information?

Comment: @Raythe I completely agree, and I did not design the website or the DB I am merely dealing with it. This is all to communicate with an Android app I have built. 2nd part 'the data comes through mixed in with the field labels?' the answer is yes. This db imo is a disaster. this is just the latest of many problems I've had while designing this software. It also doesn't help this is my first time

Comment: @Barmar an example of the `JSON` is posted. The "question" part of the `JSON` matches exactly what the column name should be and how it appears on the website. If you meant something else please explain

Comment: You wrote that you're going to duplicate rows 1 and 2, to provide the correspondence between `Column1` and `Date`. Where is that in the JSON you posted?

Comment: @Barmar oh, sorry. No the data in the db is created through an excel spread sheet. So I just duplicated row 1 & 2 in the spreadsheet so that when it imports into the DB it has correspondence. The `JSON` needs to be parsed and then inserted into the correct fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should create an associative array that maps the names of columns to the column numbers in the database schema:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('select Column1, Column2, Column3, ... from table where id = 1');
$result = $stmt->execute();
$data = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$col_map = array_flip($data);
```

You can then use this when preparing future queries of the database.

If you don't know how many columns you could have, you could do this:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('select * from table where id = 1');
$result = $stmt->execute();
$data = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
unset($data['id']); // Remove the `id` column, which doesn't conform to the ColumnN pattern
$col_map = array_flip($data);
```

Comment: I'm pretty new to this so most of that makes sense. However if I don't know how many columns I will have will this still work? Or do I need to somehow include a `for loop` in there?

Comment: Add a solution that doesn't require hard-coding the list of column names.